# Simple bind9 zone file

Tags: bind, zones

I'm setting a network in a virtual enviroinment. I have two networks, one internal (corp.net) and one external (with one name server and one client), connected by a firewall. I want that client can resolve names as www.corp.net, using the external nameserver. This is my zone.net.corp zone file:

```
$TTL 2d
$ORIGIN corp.net.
@ IN SOA server1. root.corp.net. (200405191 8H 4H 4W 1D)
    IN NS server1.

www CNAME gateway1

gateway1.corp.net. IN A 192.168.200.2
server1. IN A 192.168.200.70
```

But if i check the zonefile

```
root@server1:/etc/bind# named-checkzone zone.net zone.net.corp
zone.net.corp:6: ignoring out-of-zone data (corp.net)
zone.net.corp:9: ignoring out-of-zone data (www.corp.net)
zone.net.corp:18: ignoring out-of-zone data (gateway1.corp.net)
zone.net.corp:19: ignoring out-of-zone data (server1)
zone zone.net/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone zone.net/IN: has no NS records
```

NOTE: server1 is an external nameserver, not in the network corp.net. The hostname server1 is only specified in /etc/hostname. I want that an external machine that use as nameserver 192.168.200.70, can resolve www.corp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to named-checkzone is the zone name, not the filename.  You cannot have names like "corp.net" inside "zone.net" no matter how hard you try.

Also, your "server1" server is rooted at ., which is probably not what you want.